# imagemagick composite two png and keep it's alpha

Tags: imagemagick

I want to add watermark to my_own_png.png file by using:

```
composite -dissolve 10% -gravity center -quality 100 watermark_350.png my_own_png.png result.png
```

The result.png is not what I what, I want to keep my_own_png.png's alpha.

Please help~Thank you.

Comment: It's rather hard to help without being able to see your images...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing this...

Firstly, you could run with your current processing, which I presume you understand and are happy with, and then copy back your original image's alpha over the top of your result, like this:

```
# Your current processing
composite -dissolve 10% ... result.png

# Now add back the original image's alpha
convert result.png my_own_png.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

Or, you could do the whole lot in one go using `convert` rather than `composite`, and it will look something like this but it is hard to be sure without seeing what you are actually doing:

```
convert my_own_png.png \
   \( +clone -gravity center watermark_350.png -compose dissolve -define compose:args='10' -composite \) \
   +swap -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

That basically loads up your `my_own_png.png` and puts it to one side. It then copies it and does the dissolve with your watermark inside the parentheses. After the parentheses, the order of the images is swapped so that the watermarked image is first in the list and the original png is second in the list. It then copies the alpha from the original image and applies it to the watermarked image - hopefully :-)